# Qlik Sense - "Get Straight Table Data" does not read the table - Out: 0 items

Tags: csv, automation, business-intelligence, qliksense

Goodmorning,
i have a problem with an automation for exporting data to csv file. This Qlik Sense Cloud istance is released by our mother company and i don't have a permission to edit the table and the app. I can create a data export automation  to connect our CRM.
I use the "create file on FTP" and "Open file on FTP" for the CSV and then use the "Get Straight Table Data" and "Write Line To File on FTP" to write the data to the csv. That's fine in many situation but in one specific case "Get Straight Table Data" return 0 items e doesn't write any records to the csv file.
In the "Object ID" i tried to choose all the options but can't get the result. I think that the correct object Id is "KQEBhbm - container - row 5 col 0"
is the problem with the container? i can't modify the table e the settings.. can i solve it any method?
[Screenshot here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Up7niYMK7CZYz1LZjkini57r7jiDJ11Q/view?usp=sharing)
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to get the object ID for the table *within* the container, not the ID of the container itself. If you want to use Chrome Dev Tools, try honing in on the table object itself like so:

[image: Screenshot of how to highlight a chart object in Qlik Sense using Chrome Dev Tools]

The better way of getting an object's ID is to use the **Embed** Single Integration feature:

[image: Screen recording GIF of how to find an object ID in Qlik Sense]

- Right-click on the chart inside of the container.
- Select the **Table** option (or whatever the chart type is, just not **Container**).
- Select **Share** and then choose the **Embed** option.
- Below the chart preview, find the **Object ID**.

Comment: Happy to help! Make sure to mark the answer as being “correct” to help others find it in the future :)